# Does the aim penalty from the Suppression ability stack?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Among its other effects, the Suppression ability inflicts an aim debuff (-30 to aim) on the target.

If multiple units use Suppression on a single target, do the aim debuffs stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried this once - when you 'view' the enemy after being double suppressed - it only showed the one debuff in the list of debuffs.

Furthermore - that same unit then shot one of my units who was behind full cover...